# Changing multiple div classes at once in Jquery using an if/else statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a hangman game and I'm trying to figure out how to show two div class styles at one time using an `if` statement in jQuery but I'm having some trouble showing the second div class style change which is a red box.

If the user gets the first answer wrong it will show a yellow box and if they get it wrong a second time, it will show a red box all while adding to a counter. Please help? here's my code and thanks in advance.

```
function displayWrong() {
    jQT.goTo("#AAC6B101-LG");
    if ($("div#HMBoxButton div." + bn).hasClass("firstwrong")) {
        $("div#HMBoxButton div." + bn).addClass("wronganswer");
        $("div." + bn).unbind('touchstart');
        HMnumWrong++;
    }
    else {
        $("div#HMBoxButton div." + bn).addClass("firstwrong");
        HMnumWrong++;
        alert("Correct:" +HMnumRight+ ", Wrong:" +HMnumWrong);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the code?

Comment: when i answer the question wrong on the first try, the button image does turn yellow (first wrong class) which is good but when i answer the answer wrong again it should add to the counter and turn red which is the (wrong answer) class but it isnt....

Answer (score 1):

```
function displayWrong() {

    //since we will use the selection of the div more than once, we can cache it for better performance
    var $element = $("#HMBoxButton").find("." + bn);

    jQT.goTo("#AAC6B101-LG");

    if ($element.hasClass("firstwrong")) {

        //notice the function chaining
        $element.addClass("wronganswer").unbind('touchstart');
        HMnumWrong++;
    }
    else {
        $element.addClass("firstwrong");
        HMnumWrong++;
    }
    alert("Correct:" +HMnumRight+ ", Wrong:" +HMnumWrong);
}
```

Your code should work. So perhaps the `bn` variable is being changed between the first and second wrong answers. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f9VKY/

Comment: I put everything in like you have it and its still doing the same thing and for some strange reason not reading the second wrong change to the red image functionality. I checked my html, css, and jquery file but not seeing anything wrong and its pretty much identical to your code :-(

Comment: If you post a link I can check-out your code but I'm fairly certain you have an error or mistake somewhere else, like are you sure the class names are correct and that the property declarations in those classes are correct?

Comment: Are you accidentally resetting your HMnumWrong somewhere? Maybe try explicitly declaring the variable in the application or global scope?

Comment: @Jasper Well im new in coding in xcode and dont know how to link to my files?

Comment: @Greg I doubt that I am resetting HMnumWrong somewhere else in the code but I will research again to see..